# How to get a reference to the activity of other running application?

Tags: android

Is it even possible? It's fine if root is required.
The reason behind the question is I want to take screenshots of other apps, only found this way which requires activity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10296881/634821

Comment: with root, use the screenshot helper that adb uses, see the adb sources for your android version

Comment: try http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even possible?

No. They run in separate processes than yours -- you have no means of referencing those objects from your own process.

> The reason behind the question is I want to take screenshots of other apps

This is not supported on the device for obvious privacy and security reasons. You are welcome to use developer tools to take screenshots, as some of the comments on your question indicate.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried programs that are supposed to run on a PC and show a live picture from the connected device via adb, but their frame rate is way too low. Do you think it's possible to get at least 20 fps if making screenshots locally on the device?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: "but their frame rate is way too low" -- considering I wrote one of those, and my code was the precursor to another one, I feel your pain. :-) That is a limitation of the `adb` protocol as much as anything else. "Do you think it's possible to get at least 20 fps if making screenshots locally on the device?" -- I have no idea, as I have never tried that. I do not know if the Android Screenshot Library will be gated by the same constraints that affect tools like Droid@Screen (minus USB transfer time).