# Android: How can I get current screen image on canvas by running app in background using services

Tags: android, bitmap, screen-scraping, screenshot, android-canvas

I am new in Android app programming please some body help.. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Any of your activities can draw itself to a `Canvas` -- there are plenty of answers on SO that cover that technique, such as: [How to take a screenshot and share it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296711/androidtake-screenshot-and-share-it)

A service of yours could conceivably ask an activity of yours to draw itself to a `Canvas`, but it is unclear why the service exists.

A service of yours cannot have arbitrary other activities, ones that you did not write, take a screenshot in any form.