# How I use the image of a screenshot?

Tags: android, background, screenshot

I want to use the code of this link: [How to take a screenshot and share it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296711/androidtake-screenshot-and-share-it/10296881#10296881) to take screenshots of my application. But I want the picture which is produced to use it to change my background, like this Layout.setBackgroundResource(resid).
How I can do this?
Where I will find the image's path to use it to change Background?

Comment: Please help me guys! I am desperate....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need the view you want a screen shot of:

```
View anyView = findViewById(R.id.anyView);
```

Then use this method to take a screenshot:

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

like this:

```
Bitmap screenshot = screenShot(anyView);
```

Bitmaps can't be set as a background image so lets convert it to a drawable:

```
Drawable drawableScreenshot = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), screenshot);
```

Now set it to be the View background:

```
anyView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableScreenshot);
```