# How to test ui application android with JUNIT and take screenshots

Tags: android, testing, junit

can I run junit test on Android device and see the application running the test in the device at the same time?

If it is posible, can i take screenshots of the tests ??

I create the testcase, and works. Like this..

```
public TestCase(Class activityClass) {
    super("com.xxxx.xxxxx", xxxxxx.class);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    LoginActivity mainActivity = getActivity();
    result = (EditText) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.edit_xxx);
    result.setText("holahola");

    Button btn = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.btn_xxx);
    btn.performClick();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I run junit test on Android device and see the application running the test in the device at the same time?

Yes, though they run fairly quickly.

> If it is posible, can i take screenshots of the tests ?

You are welcome to ask the content `View` of your activity to draw itself to a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`, and this should work just fine from a unit test: [How to take a screenshot and share it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296711/androidtake-screenshot-and-share-it)